# Jsoup select query multiple elements with same class name

Tags: java, jsoup

This how the DOM looks:

```
<div class="content-section generic-section">
<div class="content-section generic-section">
<div class="content-section generic-section">
```

I need to fetch the contents from each div elements. While using select query all three contents are fetched in same variable. how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Re this:

> While using select query all three contents are fetched in same variable.

All three would be assigned to an instance of `Elements` which is a type of `ArrayList` so, in order to interrogate each of these three elements you could

- Iterate over the ArrayList: `for (Element element : elements) { ... }`
- Select entries by position: `elements.get(0)`, `elements.get(1)` etc
- Iterate over `Elements` using `prev()` and `next()`
- Select the `first()` or `last()`
- Use a visitor pattern to `traverse()` the `Elements`
- Get the `text` of each of the entries: `elements.eachText()`

Even more options in [the Javadocs](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an Elements object using select method.
As @glyching mentioned, you can traverse it.
I created test code using forEach like as below.

```
public void test() {

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><div class=\"content-section generic-section\">contents1</div><div class=\"content-section generic-section\">contents2</div><div class=\"content-section generic-section\">contents3</div></body></html>");
    // get div elements
    Elements elements = doc.select("div.content-section.generic-section");

    // display "contents1" "contents2" "contents3"
    elements.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.text()));
}
```